# Excel query - need help in setting up formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cell A and cell B.
Both the cells contain some numeric value, say 2.

Now if i put 3 in cell A, cell B value should automatically update to 5 and so on.

Again, if i put 5 in cell A, cell B value should be 10.

Hope i have made myself clear...

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: You mean when cell A is modified cell B should update itself to add the new value of cell A to its (cell B's) existing value? What happens if the user hits 'recalculate' - nothing? I'm not sure Excel can support stateful formulas like this, but maybe with a macro.

Comment: You can do it with a macro - but it honestly doesn't sound like a good idea. Can you rather explain why you want to do this? What's your end goal?

Answer (score 2):

This will work for cells A1 and B1.  Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        [B1] = [B1] + [A1]
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**